# Imported file has a wrong encoding: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 41624: character maps to

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to import a CSV file with `Django-MySQL`, using `django-import-export module`. 
My data looks like below;

```
laptops_name    laptops_url laptops_price   laptops_image   brand_name
    "Acer Predator Helios 300 PH315 144Hz (i7-8750H, 8GB, 1TB, 128GB, NV GTX1060, W10)" https://computermania.com.bd/product/acer-predator-helios-300-bd-price/ 132900  https://computermania.com.bd/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/acer_predator_helios_evl1L-240x240.jpg  Computer Mania
    "Acer Predator Helios 300 PH315 144Hz (i7-8750H, 16GB, 1TB, 128GB, NV GTX1060, W10)"    https://computermania.com.bd/product/acer-predator-helios-300-ph315144hz-refresh-rate-i7-8750h-16gb-1tb-128gb-nv-gtx1060-w10h/  138900  https://computermania.com.bd/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/acer_predator_helios_evl1L-240x240.jpg  Computer Mania
    "Asus TUF FX504G 15.6ƒ?? FHD Gaming Laptop (I5-8300H, 4GB, 1TB, GTX1050 4GB)"   https://computermania.com.bd/product/asus-tuf-fx504g-bd-price/  73900   https://computermania.com.bd/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/asus_tuf_fx504g_de40_SCd3d-240x240.jpg  Computer Mania
    "Asus TUF FX504G Gaming Laptop (I5-8300H, 8GB, 1TB, GTX1050 4GB)"   https://computermania.com.bd/product/asus-tuf-fx504g-15-6-fhd-gaming-laptop-i5-8300h-8gb-1tb-gtx1050-4gb/   77900   https://computermania.com.bd/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/asus_tuf_fx504g_de40_SCd3d-240x240.jpg  Computer Mania
    "Dell Alienware M15 Gaming Laptop (I7-8750H, 16GB, 1TB+8GB+256GB, GTX1070 8GB, W10)"    https://computermania.com.bd/product/dell-alienware-m15-price-in-bd/    199000  https://computermania.com.bd/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/dell_alienware_15_m1_DNpO4-240x240.jpg  Computer Mania
```

But I get an error like the **title** of this question. 
My django model is like below:

```
class ProductLaptop(models.Model):
    laptops_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    laptops_url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    laptops_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    laptops_image = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.laptops_name
```

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Could you post the full traceback if there is one?